# React query - cancel pending or previous requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I am trying to cancel any previous / pending requests, if they are taking too long and the user navigates to another component, currently the query takes in a state value, and when it changes the component re-renders which is fine and the desired behaviour. However looking in the network tab the requests are still pending. Is there a way in react query to cancel any previous requests. I have attempted the query cancel based on the docs but its not correct as it's not cancelling.

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const getData = async (value: number): Promise<any> => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
    const source = CancelToken.source()
    const response = await axios.get(`https://xxxxxx?value=${value}`, {
        cancelToken: source.token,
    }).then(res => res.data);
    if (CancelToken) {
        response.cancel = () => {
            source.cancel('Query was cancelled by React Query')
        }
    }
    return response;
}

const { data: result, status, error, isFetching }: any = useQuery(['getData', value], () => getData(value),
    {
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    }
);
```

Answer (score 12):

You cannot attach `.cancel` to a promise in an async functions because async functions will always return a new Promise without the cancel function you attached. If you want to attach a cancel functions, it's best to use promise chaining instead of async functions.

Even better, react-query supports cancellation now by providing an AbortSignal out of the box, which you only need to attach to your request.

with axios 0.22+ and react-query v3.30+, you can do:

```
 const query = useQuery('key', ({ signal }) =>
   axios.get('/xxxx', {
     signal,
   })
 )
```

with that, react-query will cancel the network request of your query if the query becomes unused or if you call `queryClient.cancelQueries('key')`, e.g. when the user clicks a button.

Comment: Looks like this is the solution as this is effectively built into React-query

Comment: Does this work with async functions?

Comment: Yes it does work with all functions.

Comment: Should we add queryClient.cancelQueries('key') to useEffect or it works automatically?

Comment: if you forward the signal to your data fetching function (axios, fetch, ...) then queries will be automatically cancelled when they become unused

Answer (score -2):

You need to throw out an error based on the response in your getData(). React-Query will catch that error and trigger the onError event.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? show code sample?

Comment: Errors and query cancelation are two different things.