# Cancel previous axios requests using react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I am using react-query and trying to cancel previous pending requests, I have seen some documentation on react-query but I am having trouble implementing it, so far my code is as:

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hnsgdo

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';

const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(1);

  const queryKey = 'getData';

  const getData = async (number: number): Promise<any> => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    const response = await axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${number}`, {
        cancelToken: source.token,
      })
      .then((res) => res.data);

      response.cancel = () => {
        source.cancel('Query cancelled')
    }
    
    return response;
  };

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const {
    data: result,
    isFetching,
    status,
    error,
    refetch,
  }: any = useQuery([queryKey, number], () => getData(number), {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    staleTime: 0,
    cacheTime: 0,
    refetchInterval: 0,
  });

  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <button onClick={refetch}>Refetch query</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          queryClient.cancelQueries(queryKey);
        }}
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setNumber(() => 1)}>Get 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setNumber(() => 2)}>Get 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => setNumber(() => 3)}>Get 3</button>
      <button onClick={() => setNumber(() => 99999)}>Get 99999</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      {status === 'error' && <div className="mt-5">{error.message}</div>}
      {isFetching ? (
        <div className="mt-5">Loading data ...</div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {status === 'success' && (
            <div>
              <p>
                <strong>id:</strong> {result?.id}
              </p>
              <p>{result?.title}</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React query - cancel pending or previous requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012994/react-query-cancel-pending-or-previous-requests)